# Image rewrite on NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have an application on nginx. A website linked to a image on our website that we need to do a rewrite to a new one:

```
From: /static/v20/images/lorem/ipsum/square6.png
To: /static/v31/images/ipsum/example/square8.png
```

This is what I tried:

```
rewrite ^/static/(.*)/images/lorem/ipsum/(.*).png
    /static/v31/images/ipsum/example/$2.png;
```

How I can do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^/static/(?:.+)/images/lorem/ipsum/(.+)\.png$
         /static/v31/images/ipsum/example/$1.png;
```